# PL/SQL Display Data From a Table with a Condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

i'm trying to display name and a categorie according to the participants age

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE categorie AS
     v_age NUMBER := 1;
     part_info participant%ROWTYPE;

     BEGIN 

     SELECT  *
     INTO part_info
     FROM Participant
     WHERE age > v_age;

     FOR i IN part_info
        IF(part_info.age<=18) THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || part_info.nomParticipant  || 'CATEGORIE :  JUNIOR');
      
        ELSIF(part_info.age>=50) THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || part_info.nomParticipant  || 'CATEGORIE :  SENIOR');

        ELSE 
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || part_info.nomParticipant  || 'CATEGORIE :  MIDDLE');
        END IF;
        END LOOP;
        END;
```

what am i missing ?

The Error is " Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors. "

Comment: Posting the error would be helpful so that we don't have to guess.  If I had to guess, it looks like your strings aren't properly closed.  I'd assume you'd want an open single quote before `CATEGORIE` and after the `JUNIOR|SENIOR|MIDDLE` and no single quote between them.

Comment: oh yes i missed the single quote before categorie i fixed it but its the same error " Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors. "

Comment: In `SQL*Plus`, type `show errors` to show the errors.  Or query `user_errors`.

Comment: You cannot loop over `part_info` because it's not a cursor.

Comment: Yes it was a loop problem thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firsly, opening `LOOP` is missing in the code, and error raises due to this fact. Consequently, you seem want to use a cursor rather than a `SELECT` statement alone, then replace the `part_info` qualifiers with `i` within the `LOOP`:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE categorie AS
     v_age  INT := 1;

     CURSOR part_info IS
     SELECT *      
       FROM Participant
      WHERE age > v_age;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN part_info
   LOOP     
        IF   i.age  <= 18  THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || i.nomParticipant  || '  CATEGORIE :  JUNIOR');      
        ELSIF i.age >= 50 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || i.nomParticipant  || '  CATEGORIE :  SENIOR');
        ELSE
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME: ' || i.nomParticipant  || '  CATEGORIE :  MIDDLE');
        END IF;
   END LOOP;     
END;
/
```

Comment: you're welcome @EriicButDrunk nice to help